# How can I set "Dimensions" on multiple objects? (Alt+Enter doesn't seem to work)

Tags: modeling, transforms

I'd like to be able to set Dimensions (from the <kbd>N</kbd> menu) on all the selected objects. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> works for translate and scale, but not the dimensions.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Objects can arbitrarily have the same translation and scale.  This is not the case for dimensions, eg the plane and the cube. There is no way to give the default plane, with 0 dimension in z the same dimensions as the default cube.

Comment: @batFINGER Ok, what about setting dimensions on all the selected objects together? Like the bounding box around all of them? It works in Silo...

Comment: Am postulating why this isn't available in the UI. Can do with a script eg https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160976/how-can-i-normalize-the-scale-of-what-seems-to-be-either-an-infinitely-large-o    Re multi-object bounding box. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89836/15543  (or could use a collection instance)

Comment: @batFINGER thank you!

Comment: For some reasons when you use Alt two times it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You could change multiple objects dimension if you select all of them go to edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and hit <kbd>S</kbd>