# Can't find dimensions in blender

Tags: transforms, scale, dimensions

I need to scale my model to correct size but I can't find necessary dimensions.

I am in modeling, and in object mode but still transform doesn't show dimensions. Something wrong with my config?

[image: what I'm seeing]

I usually don't use blender, therefore I can't spend hours learning it. I only need to get this single operation done. All help appreciated

Comment: hello, what kind of object have you selected? is it an empty? maybe share your file (or at least the object you've selected): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots The screenshot shows there is an empty selected. Lauri: An empty has no dimensions because it's... well, empty.

Comment: that's what I was wondering  ;)

Comment: This is an import from another software which has used empties as containers (parents) for other objects to retain hierarchy. (seen it before but can't remember which software...) Click the little arrow next to the name and it will show the other objects, then select one of the objects, or simply click it in the 3D viewport

Comment: @Psyonic That's not necessarily from a different software. People do this in Blender as well, because other than a collection you can have an empty as parent, maybe shape it so it matches a bounding box or just large enough arrows to indicate size or direction etc. of the complete model. If you now have the model set to invisible in the viewport and only see the empty, you can use this to move and rotate the model and place it in your scene without the need to display a maybe very complex model all the time.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63153/setting-exact-scale-dimension-on-multiple-objects-as-a-whole  Script here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223868/15543 calculates the combined bounding box dimension of all scene objects.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: select your tank model directly in 3D viewport window.

There is the cue. I find that the selected icon in your outliner window is an empty object. And the tank model is not highlighted. So, actually what you've selected is an empty object. And the properties showing up now is all about the empty object, not your tank model. An empty object doesn't have a "dimension" property in that panel. I guess that your tank model is a child of this empty object. We usually make an empty object (like an axis) as our model's "root".

Solution: make sure that you are selecting a REAL model which will be highlighted.

In blender, this properties panel only shows the information related to the selected object. And here is the thing, selecting a parent object doesn't means that you're selecting the whole group of objects.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get dimensions, just press  <kbd>N</kbd> key to toggle this flyout sidebar on or off.

Also you can put a checkmark in selecting *View*, the one next to the *Object* menu, and *Sidebar* will be the second item in the dropdown to do same thing.

Answer (score -1):

you can find them under scenes-> Units

[image]

And if you are searching for dimension units of your object, select it and you will see it:

[image]

Comment: is he not talking about the dimension of the object? (N panel but we can't see it in his screenshot)

Comment: @moonboots: i think you are right...but he didn't select his object. That's why...

Comment: @moonboots That's exactly it, but as you were correctly assuming he selected an empty. And I also don't think he's looking for the units.

Comment: @ Gordon Brinkmann yes you're right I didn't even take a look into the Outliner  ;)